# How to read Python list in Javascript [in a Django template]

Tags: javascript, python, django, otree

I'm programming in oTree (which is a Django based environment for social experiments) and I have the following problem. I defined some lists in Python and I'd like to import them and use them in an HTML template. If I print them in HTML I manage to see them without any problem, however, once I need to use them in Javascript, the program fails to read them and the single quotes of the elements of the list are converted in `&#39;`.
The list is imported like this `var filtered_elements = {{ array }};`.

I think the problem is exactly here, as JS cannot work with them. Do you have any suggestion on how to do that? I considered using JSON, but since I'm quite new to programming, I cannot understand if it's just a waste of time or there is a simpler way out.
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your data is already JSON, otherwise you would be getting single quotes and `u` prefixes. So the only issue is Django autoescaping; you can disable it with the `safe` filter:

```
var filtered_elements = {{ array|safe }};
```

Comment: Thanks, it really seems to work. I had the impression that it might already be working on JSON to store data between modules and templates but I wasn't super sure about it yet...

Answer (score 6):

Your data *should* be JSON, instead of putting the Python list into the contact directly, put `"array": json.dumps(array)` in the context dictionary.

The JSON string doesn't need HTML escaping inside a  tag, but it does need JS escaping! Otherwise some string may include something like `</script><script>absolutely anything goes here...` to run arbitrary JavaScript, if the JSON contains user data.

So use `|escapejs`:

```
var filtered_elements = {{ array|escapejs}};
```

Comment: Agree. btw, on the python side, when you call render (or any similar method), remember to use `json.dumps()` (ujson or simplejson). json is oriented from javascript, which provides a js-happy data serialization.

Comment: I don't understand, is it preferable |safe or |escapejs, what's the difference?

Comment: Usually Django automatically applies HTML escaping, that's what you saw (`'` to `&#39;` and so on). JavaScript isn't HTML, so you don't need that. `|safe` merely marks a string as already escaped, so no escaping is applied to it. `|escapejs` applies the kind of escaping you need for JS inside a `<script>` tag. So it's what you need.