# List in template tag used in javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, eval

As title say I want to use list from views.py to javascript file.
I read this topic, but in my case it doesn't work: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678583/how-to-read-python-list-in-javascript-in-a-django-template)

My views.py:

```
...
arr = ['first', 'second', 'third']
return render(request, "something.html",{"array": arr})
...
```

something.html:

```
...
<script>
     array_js = eval("{{ array|escapejs }}");
</script>
<script src="{% whatever.js %}"></script>
...
```

I am using array_js in whatever.js file. It's works fine, but I am using eval function. I don't want to use it, but I don't know how to make it work without eval function.

I am beginner, so please be patient. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since arrays are considered valid JSON, you can just use `JSON.parse`:

```
array_js = JSON.parse('{{ array|escapejs }}')
```

But be sure to set it as an JSON on the view:

```
import json

...

return render(request, "something.html", {"array": json.dumps(arr)})
```